# How to navigate through local folders in command promt

Tags: cmd

I am a rookie who just started coding in python. I need to run the python files through cmd. Once I direct to a specific folder, I don't know the command line to direct me back to the root folder. Please do help in the earliest

Comment: Use the command `cd /?` for information about how to use the `cd` command.

Answer (score 0):

"cd directory" will lead you to a folder
"cd .." will bring you back one folder up